# Humidity sensor over I2C saturated

Tags: raspberry-pi, sensors

I have RasPi 3 with following sensors on I2C bus: [BME280](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwihhqjds83VAhUB1hQKHcIpBbEQFgg5MAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn-shop.adafruit.com%2Fdatasheets%2FBST-BME280_DS001-10.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGogGEvMOwdqvdGd2AMsqytUTKKZA), [BH1750](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj89an2s83VAhUG0RQKHYMIBn8QFgg7MAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcpre.kmutnb.ac.th%2Fesl%2Flearning%2Fbh1750-light-sensor%2Fbh1750fvi-e_datasheet.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHynwyc4eZpllLc7Ckitynb8-D96A), [MLX90614](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Temperature/MLX90614_rev001.pdf).

All data from all sensors is read OK.
After 4 months of use BME280 got stuck at 100% of relative humidity (rH).
Temperature and pressure readings are valid and precise at that time.
Power cycle didn't help. Code review/rewrite didn't help.

I added [HTU21D](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/1899_HTU21D.pdf) sensor for reference. At the same time the BME280 was stuck at maximal calculate rH, the HTU21D read correct and valid valued for bith humidity and temperature.

After 2 months more, the HTU21D screwed up and started to show 76-118% of rH while the temperature reading are correct and precise (similar behavior to BME280). In spite HTU21D is not stuck at single value, it's measurement is wrong. Strange thing, in dark time it's always 118% rH.
Raw data from rH reading of HTU21D is:

- 255, 255, 45 (or 0xFFFF2D).

That means CRC is OK and the sensor thinks it reports correct value. As well, correct CRC and other data readings OK mean the I2C bus is build properly too.

Code tried:

- [BME280 code example](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2016/07/using-bme280-i2c-temperature-pressure-sensor-in-python/): not altered since many people use it and no complaints.
- [Adafruit BME280 code example](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_BME280): Doesn't work, I/O errors.
- [Example 1](https://github.com/raspberrypi/weather-station/blob/master/HTU21D.py). Reads, however wrong humidity after 2 months.
- [Example 2](https://github.com/randymxj/Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code/blob/master/Adafruit_HTU21D/Adafruit_HTU21D.py). Doesn't work, stated in the example explicitly, I/O errors.
- An attempt to adjust timing from write 0xF5 to HTU21D to reading 3
  bytes didn't help.
- An attempt to read values from HTU21D with i2cset
  and i2cget had no success.
- An attempt to remove HTU21D reset before
  reading or double reset or increase/decrease time after reset didn't
  help.

As the same time, the BME280 is still got stuck at 100% rH: pure calculated values are 150-180%, limited in software to 100%.

I2C bus details:

- Cable length is about 55 cm, 22".
- Voltage 3.3V.
- Pull-up resistors on SCL and SDA 4.7K.

Did anybody encounter the problem when part of data of 2 similar sensors from different manufacturers is stuck at higher numbers and other data is OK?

What can be a reason that just humidity is wrong while other data is correct?

Comment: Souds like the sensor is simply broken. Have you tried a different sensor?

Comment: I thought the sensor is broken after 4 months, so I put other sensor of other vendor. It's broken in 2 months. Now I put new 2 sensors and they work. My concern is reliability of sensors. Shouldn't they work more than 2-4 months?

Comment: What conditions are you using them in? Any condensation? There is an HTU21DF which has a protective membrane over the sensor, perhaps that might help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quote from the [Si7021 datasheet](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/Si7021-A20.pdf) (not one of the sensors in the question but I believe this applies to humidity sensors in general) with some relevant emphasis:

> Prolonged exposure to high humidity will result in a gradual upward drift of
> the RH reading. The shift in sensor reading resulting from this drift will
> generally disappear slowly under normal ambient conditions. The amount of
> shift is proportional to the magnitude of relative humidity and the length of
> exposure. **In the case of lengthy exposure to high humidity, some of the
> resulting shift may persist indefinitely under typical conditions.** It is
> generally possible to substantially reverse this affect by baking the device.